# Marginal density function comes out negative

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

I am having a problem understanding marginal functions in a class problem.

The exercise says:

Given the bidimensional density function $f(x,y)=6(3x-y)$ when $0<x<y\leq 1$ 
Find the probability of X being lower than 0.5.

I follow as I found in textbooks and find the marginal density function to integrate between 0 and $1/2$.

So. $\int_{x}^{1} 6(3x-y)dy = 6(-5/2x^2 + 3x - 1/2)$

But then I realized that this function has negative area from $x=0$ to $x=1/5$ which blows my mind because there can’t be a negative probability in that interval.

I made sure integral was correct in wolfram alpha, so the only thing that I can think of could explain it is that is not the way to get the marginal function, but it is the way I see everywhere and makes sense to me.

Any hint of what is happening here? Thanks!

Comment: This indeed cannot be the density of a probability measure since it needs to be positive, for $3x<y$ there is a problem, where is the exercise from ?

Comment: It’s from an exam made two years ago in my university.

Comment: The thing is it doesn't even integrate to $1$, are you sure the domain is not something like $0\leq x \leq y \leq 3x \leq 1$ or so ?

Comment: Hmmm, I am pretty sure it integrates to 1 with those limits (just checked in wolfram alpha, x from 0 to 1, y from x to 1).